# ¿Cómo añadir caracteres a un array char en C++?

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo añadir caracteres al final de un array char?

```
int co2 = 9000;
float temp = 22.12;
float hum = 54.88;

 char co2C[9];
 char tempC[8];
 char humC[7];
 
  sprintf(co2C, "%i", co2);
   sprintf(tempC, "%.2f", temp);
    sprintf(humC, "%.2f", hum);

  co2C = co2C +"PPM"; // esto es lo que me gustaría conseguir
```

El tipo para convertir a char co2 tiene que un int no puedo realizar la conversion desde un String

Comment: es un programa en arduino el cual muestro los datos en un label con la librería LVGL en un display,  estos labels solo admiten el tipo char, probando con recoger los datos del co2, temp o hum en un string me da errores al realizar el sprintf y no se visualizan por pantalla

Comment: casi lo tienes hecho. solo te falta el último sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con otro `sprintf` podrías hacerlo:

```
sprintf( co2C, "%s%s", co2C, "PPM");
```

o también:

```
sprintf( co2C, "%sPPM", co2C);
```

Ya lo estabas haciendo, pero en este caso añades dos cadenas.

Comment: Este código fallará, `co2C` tiene tamaño 7 y `9000PPM` ocupa todos los caracteres sin dejar espacio para el finalizador de cadena.

Comment: Cuando lo he leído yo, tenía tamaño 9.

Comment: Perdón, tiene tamaño 9, lo leí mal :(

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cómo puedo añadir caracteres al final de un array char?

No puedes, los array<sup>1</sup> tienen tamaño fijo, no se les pueden añadir datos.

Si quieres convertir números a texto en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

- Usa `std::stringstream`.
- No uses array de caracteres, usa `std::string`.
- No uses herramientas de [c](/questions/tagged/c) como `sprintf`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int co2 = 9000;
    std::string co2C;
 
    std::stringstream stream;

    stream << co2;
    stream >> co2C;

    co2C = co2C + "PPM";

    std::cout << co2C;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU69CsIwEJ57T3HURREhuNmkWZyFvkJISwm0l9Ikk/jsMUmr4vTx/d7pZbnoSdEY48GQnkI/oDDW@XVQs4Sf5j4SGPI4K0PHEzyhykzbK7Z4Y4xxqJzvmyaFDY3ZuHPAP3HbwQ04ZK8IQuQ4/3Ip9zpUGdOBAmesu@5Rb8U0qm3we7dk18GHlTB98orxDQ)</kbd>.

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocidos como *formaciones* o *arreglos*.

Comment: @mourazo La libreria posiblemente tome un `char*`, asi que puedes hacerlo con el `std::string` y luego lo lo pasas como: `co2C.c_str()`